# How do I override a parent's method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

let's suppose we have an object `Person` as follows:

```
function Person(name){
            this.name = name;

            this.greeting = function(){
                alert("Hi I'm " + this.name);
            }
        }
```

and its child

```
function Teacher(name, subject){
            Person.call(this, name); 
            this.subject = subject;
            Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
        }
```

I tried to override `greeting` method as follows:

```
Teacher.prototype.greeting = function(){                
                alert("Hello my name is " + this.name + " and I teach " + this.subject);

        }
```

but `teacher1.greeting()` invokes `Person`'s method and not `Teacher`'s one, as you can see here:

[image: Person's method invoked and not Teacher's one]

- Where's the mistake?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] to show how exactly are you calling this code?

Comment: Ok I've just edited

Comment: You still haven't shown how this code is being called. Please [make a runnable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: You will need to a) define the parent `greeting` method on `Person.prototype`, not inside the constructor, and b) move the `Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)` outside of the `Teacher` constructor.

Comment: Maybe it's not necessary to b) because I tried  @dmigo solution and works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:
Now that I'm home and on a laptop, I see the bug. You set the Teacher prototype in the wrong place.

So you needed to do this:

```js
// Incorrect
function Teacher(first, last, age, gender, interest, subject) {
  Person.call(this, first, last, age, gender, interest);
  this.subject = subject;
  Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
}

// Correct
function Teacher(first, last, age, gender, interest, subject) {
  Person.call(this, first, last, age, gender, interest);
  this.subject = subject;
}

Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

Because of this, every time you instantiated a new instance of `Teacher`, you would override it’s prototype with `Person`. So no matter what you set the Teacher's prototype to, it was getting overwritten.

Comment: I don't have to use them

Comment: @HeyBoo Well! That's a reason.

Comment: I followed this guide https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance but it does not work properly

Comment: You would need to put the method override into the `Object.create` call inside the teacher function.

Answer (score 0):

In your first class `greeting` function on Person function prototype.
If you use `this` in constructor function, then you refer to newly created object, not to function's prototype. This is correct way if you want to override prototype function:

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greeting = function(){
    alert("Hi I'm " + this.name);
}
```

You can compare this code with yours by checking value of `Person.prototype.greeting`.

That's why you couldn't override it with Teacher class, cause `greeting` function was overwritten by Person constructor every time you create Teacher object and call it's constructor.

Comment: You don't have to change the prototype in the constructor.

Comment: @VLAZ, you're right, it makes no sense. I modified my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define `greeting` as an *instance method* in `Person`. It should be a method of `Person.prototype`. Why? Because when you reference a property of an instance the interpreter always *first* checks for existence of instance properties, *then* the constructor prototype properties of an instance.

So this should work:

```js
const someTeacher = new Teacher("Peter", "Jones", 26, "Male", "Functional Programming", "Math");
someTeacher.greeting();

function Person(first, last, age, gender, interest) {
  this.name = {
    first,
    last
  };
  this.age = age;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.interest = interest;
  
  // set the Person.prototype greeting method
  // if not already done
  if (!Person.prototype.greeting) {
    Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
      console.log("Hi I'm " + this.name.first);
    };
  }
}

function Teacher(first, last, age, gender, interest, subject) {
  Person.call(this, first, last, age, gender, interest);
  this.subject = subject;
  
  // set Teachers prototype to Person
  // if not already done
  if (!Teacher.prototype.greeting) {
    // override [greeting] first. If you do this after
    // pointing the prototype to Person, it wil not
    // work, probably because in that case you're
    // overwriting Person.prototype.greeting which is
    // a nogo
    Teacher.prototype.greeting = function() {
      console.log("Hello my name is " + this.name.first + " and I teach " + this.subject);
    };
    // set prototype to Person
    Teacher.prototype = Person;
  }
}
```